# Google API: How do I discover the client secret for an existing API Key?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-developers-console

A while back I created an API Key in Google API's.

I'm navigating around the API Key UI. I can see the API Key. But I can't see any way of revealing the client secret.

Is there a way to recover the secret?
Or do I have to regenerate the key and secret, thus breaking any existing application currently using it?

Comment: it is available under `OAuth 2.0 Client IDs` in `Credentials`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to [google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?)  find the credential you are after.  Then click the pencil icon on that row.  It will open a new window where you can see your client secret.

[image]